Exploring DNA-Based Hard Structures for Space Applications—Looking to learn more
I recently had a fascinating conversation with a student about to graduate with a master's in microbiology. He shared that he’s lined up a job where he'll work on developing "hard structures" from DNA, including concepts like self-healing bridges. This conversation opened up possibilities that seemed almost like science fiction, such as bioships and structures for space environments that can repair themselves.
While I found some preliminary research on using DNA as a building material, information seems sparse, especially regarding large-scale applications or space research. Here are a couple of resources I found that discuss the technology on a smaller scale:
Making Structures with DNA “Building Blocks”
https://wyss.harvard.edu/media-post/making-structures-with-dna-building-blocks/
Recent Advances in the Use of DNA as a Building Material



Does anyone know of research that is exploring the use of DNA for constructing large-scale structures, particularly for space applications?
Thank you!

just fyi we have several questions on the use of wood and bamboo as well, and DNA is indeed a surprisingly robust material: Was 14,000+ year old DNA "laying around in cave dirt" protected from degradation, or is it just naturally this robust? And here's what a glob of wet DNA looks like

I mean, DNA strands break down pretty significantly if exposed to ionizing radiation or strong UV. That's a big deal in space. DNA fragments can survive long-term, but that's a function of having already been cut into tiny pieces. Long strands like what you'd need for structures or to control protein production are pretty fragile.

14,000+ years is unfathomable. I had no idea that DNA could "survive" for so long. I also agree that ionizing radiation or UV would be an issue for this material.
I could almost see an inner wall membrane layer acting almost like a seal that could self-heal.

May be if you could genetically modify some species of vines, you could harden them for space. Then you could twine them together for added tensile strength.

Also this bamboo looks interesting. Scientists chemically remove the lignin from the wood fibers, then treat the remaining material with plexiglass or epoxy. The end result is a material that’s transparent, renewable, and as strong as or stronger than glass, while being lighter and a better thermal insulator. https://newatlas.com/materials/transparent-bamboo-fireproof-waterproof/
